# Error using CGRectUnion of UIbuttons

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Im trying to detect wether or not, when I spawn two uibuttons, if they are united via `CGRectUnion`.

I coded:

```
if CGRectUnion(button1.frame, button2.frame){

}
```

but I get an error saying:
Statement requires expression of scalar type`('CGRect'(aka 'struct CGRect') invalid)`

Please help if you have the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`CGRectIntersectsRect()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) instead:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(button1.frame, button2.frame)) {

}
```

`CGRectUnion()` does something entirely different.

Comment: how would you suggest to detect if theCGRectUnion returns an object or not?